# BlueprintJS : SUGGEST => How to limit the row number on the popover?

Tags: javascript, blueprintjs

How to limit the displayed row number (add a scollbar) in the popOver with the "Suggest" component of BluePrintJS ?

```
<Suggest
    items={this.state.Plats}
    activeItem={this.state.activePlat}
    onActiveItemChange={this.handleActiveItemChange}
    itemRenderer={renderPlat}
    itemPredicate={filterFilm}
    onItemSelect={this.handleClick}
    noResults={<MenuItem disabled={true} text="Pas de résultat." />}
    inputValueRenderer={this.renderValue}
    popoverProps={{minimal: true, usePortal: true}}
/>

const filterFilm: ItemPredicate<IPlat> = (query, plat) => {
    const text = `${plat.Nom}`;
     return text.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
};

const renderPlat: ItemRenderer<IPlat> = (Plat, { handleClick, modifiers}) => 
{
  if (!modifiers.matchesPredicate){
    return null;
  }
  const text = `${Plat.Key}. ${Plat.Nom}`;
  return <MenuItem 
    key={Plat.Key} 
    active={modifiers.active}
    disabled={modifiers.disabled}
    label={Plat.Categorie}
    onClick={handleClick} 
    text={text} />;
};
```

[Here is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giLVS.png)

I'd like to limit the list to 10 items, as in the example on the site, but everything I tried didn't work.

Thanks for any advice or help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The image you've displayed isn't the normal style for a `Suggest` component. Are you including the `Suggest` CSS file? Make sure that is added because that will limit the height of the `popover` and make the content scrollable rather than a huge list across the entire height of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the long delay.
I will check and keep you informed.

Comment: Many thanks.  It was the correct answer.
Just one thing, it's 'blueprint-select.css', but you gave me a very strong hint ;)

Comment: Glad to hear I could help. I have ran into a similar issue before, so I had an inclination to what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `itemListRenderer` prop. From the [docs](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#select/select-component.javascript-api):

> ItemListRenderer
> Custom renderer for the contents of the dropdown.
>
> The default implementation invokes itemRenderer for each item that passes the predicate and wraps them all in a Menu element. If the query is empty then initialContent is returned, and if there are no items that match the predicate then noResults is returned.
> Inherited from IListItemsProps.itemListRenderer

You can customize the prop with your own renderer function. In your case, you can probably lift [the default renderer code](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/9145edd2c88adf3da49fff7a23204602a3f01598/packages/select/src/components/query-list/queryList.tsx#L205) and add a line where you limit the number of items to X.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  
I use an itemListRenderer.

I think the way to resolve is with the CSS, as user5661402 mentioned.

Anyway, I'll post as soon as I test